# Print a line of HTML, keeping the right format

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I must print all the raw text of this [HTML page](https://cm.jefferson.edu/rna22/Precomputed/InputController?download=ALL&ident=hsa_miR_107%20hsa_miR_5011_5p%20hsa_miR_326&minBasePairs=12&maxFoldingEnergy=-12&minSumHits=1&maxProb=.1&version=MB21E78v2&species=HomoSapiens&type=mRNA).

Each line has this format:

```
ENSG00000001461'&nbsp';'&nbsp';'&nbsp';'&nbsp';ENST00000432012'&nbsp';'&nbsp';'&nbsp';'&nbsp';NIPAL3'&nbsp';'&nbsp';'&nbsp';'&nbsp';5'&nbsp';'&nbsp';'&nbsp';'&nbsp';1'&nbsp';'&nbsp';'&nbsp';'&nbsp';Forward'&nbsp';'&nbsp';'&nbsp';'&nbsp';NIPA-like domain containing 3 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:25233]<'br/'>
```

I want the following output:

```
ENSG00000001461    ENST00000432012    NIPAL3    5    1    Forward    NIPA-like domain containing 3 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:25233]
```

But the output is only:

```
ENSG00000001461
```

This is my code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
species = ['HomoSapiens', 'MusMusculus', 'DrosophilaMelanogaster','CaenorhabditisElegans']
rna_target = ['mRNA', 'lincRNA', 'lncRNA']
db = ['MB21E78v2', 'MB19E65v2', 'MB16E62v1']

species_input = input("Selezionare Specie: ")
target_input = input("Selezionare tipo di RNA: ")
db_input = input("Selezionare DataBase: ")
check = 0

for i in range(len(species)):
    if species_input == species[i]:
        for j in range(len(rna_target)):
            if target_input == rna_target[j]:
                for k in range(len(db)):
                    if db_input == db[k]:
                        check = 1
if check == 1:
    print("Dati Inseriti Correttamente!")
else:
    print("Error: Dati inseriti in modo errato!")
    exit()

url =   urllib.request.urlopen("<https://cm.jefferson.edu/rna22/Precomputed/OptionController?>" +"species=" + species_input + "&type=" + target_input + "&version=" +db_input)
print(url.geturl())

identifier = []
seq_input = input("Digitare ID miRNA: ")
seq = ""
seq = seq_input.split()
print(seq)

for i in range(len(seq)):
    identifier.append(seq[i] + "%20")
s = ""
string = s.join(identifier)

url_tab = urllib.request.urlopen("<https://cm.jefferson.edu/rna22/Precomputed/InputController?>"+"identifier=" string+"&minBasePairs=12&maxFoldingEnergy=-12&minSumHits=1&maxProb=.1&"+"version=" + db_input + "&species=" + species_input + "&type=" + target_input)
print(url_tab.geturl())

download = urllib.request.urlopen("
<http://cm.jefferson.edu/rna22/Precomputed/InputController?>download=ALL"+"&ident=" + string+"&minBasePairs=12&maxFoldingEnergy=-12&minSumHits=1&maxProb=.1&" +"version=" + db_input + "&species=" + species_input + "&type=" + target_input)
down_string = download.geturl()
print(down_string)
soup = BeautifulSoup(download, "html5lib")
for match in soup.findAll('br'):
    match.unwrap()
s2 = soup
s1 = s2.body.extract()
print(s1.prettify(formatter=lambda s: s.strip(u'xa0')))
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Put a [mcve] *in the question itself*; where is the Python?

Comment: @Selcuk              This is not a code written by me..My professor give me the task to write a python program that download on my pc an html page as a txt file. I have no idea if it is possible!  the page is to this [link]:  (https://cm.jefferson.edu/rna22/Precomputed/InputController?download=ALL&ident=hsa_miR_107%20hsa_miR_5011_5p%20hsa_miR_326&minBasePairs=12&maxFoldingEnergy=-12&minSumHits=1&maxProb=.1&version=MB21E78v2&species=HomoSapiens&type=mRNA)

Comment: I'm sorry if i'm not clear but this is the first time that i use stackowerflow so 
I don't know how to use it well!

Comment: @Federico93, share your link if possible and your code so far

Comment: Since we don't know what you are passing to we cannot help you.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham, I have add my code and the link of the html page

Comment: @Federico93, you need to add some example input so the code can be run

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham As input, for 0<i,j,k<2,  yuo can pass:  species_input=species[i], targhet_input=rna_target[j], db_input=db[k].                                                     Example: species_input='HomoSapiens', target_input='mRNA', db_input='MB21E78v2.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no notion of lines in the source, there is just one long line of text which you need to separate using newlines using the br tags.

If you have to parse the source, you can replace the br tags with newlines and just pull the text:

```
import  requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://cm.jefferson.edu/rna22/Precomputed/InputController?download=ALL&ident=hsa_miR_107%20hsa_miR_5011_5p%20hsa_miR_326&minBasePairs=12&maxFoldingEnergy=-12&minSumHits=1&maxProb=.1&version=MB21E78v2&species=HomoSapiens&type=mRNA")

soup =  BeautifulSoup(r.content)
for b in soup.find_all("br"):
    b.replace_with("\n")
print(soup.text)
```

Which will give you:

```
ENSG00000001461    ENST00000432012    NIPAL3    5    1    Forward    NIPA-like domain containing 3 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:25233]
ENSG00000001631    ENST00000340022    KRIT1    5    7    Reverse    KRIT1, ankyrin repeat containing [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:1573]
ENSG00000001631    ENST00000394503    KRIT1    3    7    Reverse    KRIT1, ankyrin repeat containing [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:1573]
ENSG00000001631    ENST00000394505    KRIT1    3    7    Reverse    KRIT1, ankyrin repeat containing [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:1573]
ENSG00000001631    ENST00000394507    KRIT1    4    7    Reverse    KRIT1, ankyrin repeat containing [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:1573]
ENSG00000001631    ENST00000412043    KRIT1    4    7    Reverse    KRIT1, ankyrin repeat containing [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:1573]
ENSG00000002834    ENST00000318008    LASP1    6    17    Forward    LIM and SH3 protein 1 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:6513]
ENSG00000002834    ENST00000433206    LASP1    6    17    Forward    LIM and SH3 protein 1 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:6513]
ENSG00000002834    ENST00000435347    LASP1    5    17    Forward    LIM and SH3 protein 1 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:6513]
ENSG00000005381    ENST00000225275    MPO    5    17    Reverse    myeloperoxidase [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:7218]
ENSG00000005889    ENST00000539115    ZFX    4    23 X    Forward    zinc finger protein, X-linked [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:12869]
ENSG00000006432    ENST00000554752    MAP3K9    10    14    Reverse    mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase kinase 9 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:6861]
ENSG00000006432    ENST00000611979    MAP3K9    10    14    Reverse    mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase kinase 9 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:6861]
ENSG00000007216    ENST00000314669    SLC13A2    4    17    Forward    solute carrier family 13 (sodium-dependent dicarboxylate transporter), member 2 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:10917]
ENSG00000007216    ENST00000444914    SLC13A2    4    17    Forward    solute carrier family 13 (sodium-dependent dicarboxylate transporter), member 2 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:10917]
```

And a whole lot more of the same.

Answer (score -1):

I tested your code and replaced my previous answer.

If you edit the following errors, your code seems to work.

- Remove < from the urls
- Remove EOL in line 42
- Add a + between "identifiers=" and string

Here are some of the lines of the output I get:

```
 ENSG00000272325    ENST00000607016    NUDT3    4    6    Reverse    nudix (nucleoside diphosphate linked moiety X)-type motif 3 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:8050]
 ENSG00000272980    ENST00000400926    CCR6    5    6    Forward    chemokine (C-C motif) receptor 6 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:1607]
 ENSG00000274211    ENST00000612932    SOCS7    8    17    Forward    suppressor of cytokine signaling 7 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:29846]
 ENSG00000274588    ENST00000611977    DGKK    4    23 X    Reverse    diacylglycerol kinase, kappa [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:32395]
 ENSG00000275004    ENST00000613655    ZNF280B    4    22    Reverse    zinc finger protein 280B [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:23022]
 ENSG00000275004    ENST00000619852    ZNF280B    4    22    Reverse    zinc finger protein 280B [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:23022]
 ENSG00000275832    ENST00000622683    ARHGAP23    6    17    Forward    Rho GTPase activating protein 23 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:29293]
 ENSG00000277258    ENST00000616199    PCGF2    3    17    Reverse    polycomb group ring finger 2 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:12929]
 ENSG00000278871    ENST00000623344    KDM5D    8    24 Y    Reverse    lysine (K)-specific demethylase 5D [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:11115]
 ENSG00000279096    ENST00000622918    AL356289.1    11    1    Forward    HCG1780467 {ECO:0000313|EMBL:EAX06861.1}; PRO0529 {ECO:0000313|EMBL:AAF16687.1}  [Source:UniProtKB/TrEMBL;Acc:Q9UI23]
```

Comment: this code produce this error:                                                                                                                                                                                                                            print (myfile.replace("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;","\t").replace("<br />","\n"))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'